# WSO2 EI, how to stream or pipe file response to user?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have REST API url method, that will return file as its response and I need to wrap it around with my WSO2 EI REST API.

Is it possible to stream or pipe this file based response back to requested user, without storing this file?

Comment: What do you mean "wrap it around"? Indeed it is possible (and adviced) to stream the messages not necessarily parsing them

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the wso2 file connector[1] to read the file as a stream inside the API sequence. You can download and enable the file connector as in the doc[2]. Follow the "Reading content from a file" section in [1] and you should be able to set the **streaming** optional parameter to true. Also, follow the *Note* section to enable streaming for large files.

A sample API sequence is shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
     name="fileStream"
     context="/file-stream"
     version="1.0"
     version-type="context">
   <resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/test">
      <inSequence>
    <fileconnector.read>
        <source>{source_location}</source>
        <filePattern>{file_pattern}</filePattern>
        <contentType>{content_type}</contentType>
        <streaming>true</streaming>
    </fileconnector.read>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector
[2] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/File+Connector